# String start with and end with anything (but is not .php)

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to make a redirection URL in htaccess.
I want to redirect URLs like

```
www.domain.com/pageANYTHING
```

to

```
www.domain.com
```

But I have an exception : when I got this

```
www.domain.com/page.phpANYTHING
```

do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact It works with a mix of your two propositions.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:php)$  
RewriteRule ^page(?!\.php).*$ / [R=301,L]
```

Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\.phpANYTHING [NC]
RewriteRule ANYTHING$ http://www.domain.com/? [L,R,NC]
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, It is almost working perfect but I got one little problem. The redirection is working but the URL in the browser does not update to www.domain.com. Is it possible to update the URL ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page(?!\.php).*$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, It is almost working perfect but I got one little problem. The redirection is working but the URL in the browser does not update to www.domain.com. Is it possible to update the URL ?

Comment: Updated... it performs a 301 redirect now.